# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14559, 1455900]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, prediction

I am facing some problems when I try to fit the model. This happens when I try to use LogisticRegression, Naive bayes or svm models. But I get results when I use random forest regression or decision tree.

The error says:

> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (20799, 100)
> instead.

The solution is to use y_train.ravel() when I fit the model. But then again, the below error appears:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14559,
> 1455900]

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df=pd.read_csv('../input/filteredbymany.csv',low_memory=False,usecols=['county','crashalcoh','drvrsex','developmen','lightcond','drvrvehtyp','drvrage','pedage','city','crashloc','crashtype','pedpos'])

df.dropna(inplace=True)

dummies= pd.get_dummies(df)
merged=pd.concat([df,dummies],axis='columns')
X = merged
X = X.drop(['county','crashalcoh','city','developmen','drvrage','drvrsex','drvrvehtyp','lightcond','pedage','crashloc','crashtype','pedpos'],axis='columns')

y = X.loc[:, X.columns.str.startswith('county')]

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train.values.ravel())
model.predict(X_test)
```

I have been struggling with this for around 80 hours or so. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

You want to have an array `X` with N rows. Each row is a sample of something and each column is a feature of these samples. And then you want to have an array `y` with N values. The i'th value of `y` is the value ("label") you want to predict for the i'th row of `X`.

## The first error

Your `y` is two-dimensional (shape is `(N, 100)`), but it should be one-dimensional (shape `(N,)`). So you have 100 labels for each instance in `X`, but the model you chose can only predict one label per instance.

## The second error

Then you `ravel` it to a one-dimensional array with shape `(100*N,)`. Now you have one dimension, but still too many values.

## Solution

Look at your tables `X` and `y` and see which column of `y` you actually want.

Comment: The thing is. I want to predict a Categorical variable. In this case, I want to predict my county column where the accidents have occurred. So, I pushed the whole dataset along into get_dummies(df) and have the dummy variables for all of them.therefore, i had to take all the columns of label(y).  Then I have split the columns to get X and y. then did the train_test_split(). 

Is my approach correct to predict a categorical column? Can you suggest me a better one?

Comment: If your real labels look like `['US', 'US', 'Germany', 'India', ...]` with 100 different countries, then instead of making it a Nx100 binary dummy table, you can encode them as `[0, 0, 1, 2, ...]`, where each country has a unique integer label. Have a look at [pd.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).

Comment: Thank you sir ;-;